# How does Entity Framework Core know and identify which record to update?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Hopefully a quick one, I'm new to C# / .NET Core / Entity Framework etc. but need to use it for work so apologies if this makes no sense.

I'm going to update a record using Entity Framework Core update method, but I'm not sure how it identifies which record to update? Does it compare the record's ID?

My plan is to replace the original entity with a new entity with new values every time - but the ID will remain the same, is this sufficient or do I need to map the new properties to the existing entity?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No not yet was hoping to find out before, it's CSV uploads so I'm putting off trying until I'm *pretty* sure it will work as expected

Comment: This feels like you should be running through some basic EF tutorials rather than asking questions on here. There's a lot to learn about EF, and answering this one small point isn't enough for you to use it effectively and safely.

Comment: Yes - it uses the **primary key** of the record to track which records have been modified. That's one of the reasons a primary key is a **must** in EF Core.

Comment: The EF Core's concept you are looking for is "Tracking" :  [Tracking - Identity resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#identity-resolution)

Comment: CSV uploads... EF can do this, but SQL Bulk can be easiest and more performant.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks this is perfect, am I correct in assuming it will match the primary key and then completely overwrite the rest of the record / cascade deleting the necessary linked records in the process?

Comment: @vernou EF Bulk Extensions does OK

Comment: @mattavero it depends how you set up your cascades around your entity graph, and from a bulk perspective I'd expect some challenges. If the incoming data laready has a PK in it, then you might as well dispense with the "update the main" approach and have a cascading delete of the main, then reinsert the complete new data

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks I will look in to this!

Comment: *is this sufficient* -- That depends 100% on how you implement it. That's why this question can't be answered without at least seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Check that source here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution
Everything for ef core tracking.

Entity instances become tracked when they are:

Returned from a query executed against the database
Explicitly attached to the DbContext by Add, Attach, Update, or similar methods
Detected as new entities connected to existing tracked entities
Entity instances are no longer tracked when:

The DbContext is disposed
The change tracker is cleared (EF Core 5.0 and later)
The entities are explicitly detached